# groupBy in data.table: Use first value

Tags: r, data.table

I have a huge `data.table` in R which contains the result of a experiment: For each result, the id of the run and the configuration parameter is contained in two other rows. The `conf` parameter is constant for every run. See this simplified example:

```
> x=data.table(runId=rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),each=5),conf=rep(c(10,10,500,500,1000,1000), each=5), value=runif(30,1, 1000))
> x
   runId conf     value
       1   10 102.17366
       1   10 739.31317
       1   10 361.83867
       1   10 915.05966
       1   10 435.11605
       2   10 254.13930
       2   10 482.93782
       2   10 598.34327
       2   10 401.45823
       2   10 480.17624
       3  500 831.03700
       3  500 378.53013
       3  500 371.75072
       3  500  61.27925
       3  500 425.50863
       4  500 557.64415
       4  500 731.07127
       4  500 836.31104
       4  500 138.61641
       4  500 106.12334
       5 1000 925.24886
       5 1000 840.06707
       5 1000 680.79559
       5 1000 402.77619
       5 1000 507.21966
       6 1000 111.93297
       6 1000 100.88960
       6 1000 149.17332
       6 1000 444.28845
       6 1000 654.86640
```

I want to calculate the means of the values for each run, I can do this by using:

```
> x[,list(mean=mean(value)),by=runId]
    runId     mean
[1,]     1 634.1549
[2,]     2 275.1270
[3,]     3 328.4098
[4,]     4 584.1364
[5,]     5 616.1647
[6,]     6 411.2354
```

I also want to add the `conf` value to each of the rows in the aggregate. I fact I can obtain this result by also using the `mean` function of the `conf` column. But: This is useless as the conf-value does not change at all for each runId:

```
> x[,list(conf=mean(conf),mean=mean(value)),by=runId]
     runId conf     mean
[1,]     1   10 634.1549
[2,]     2   10 275.1270
[3,]     3  500 328.4098
[4,]     4  500 584.1364
[5,]     5 1000 616.1647
[6,]     6 1000 411.23
```

**Is there another alternative to this hacky mean-function here? Something like a "first" function (or a "last", it doesn't mind in this case) which I can use to aggregate?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, got an answer on the IRC just as I finished this question. As I already posted this question, perhaps someone finds this usable although the result is quite obvious:

To get the first result, simply use `column[1]`. So the example above boils down to:

```
> x[,list(conf=conf[1], mean=mean(value)), by=runId]
     runId conf     mean
[1,]     1   10 634.1549
[2,]     2   10 275.1270
[3,]     3  500 328.4098
[4,]     4  500 584.1364
[5,]     5 1000 616.1647
[6,]     6 1000 411.23
```